# Delete html tags using sed/grep/awk

Tags: grep, sed

If we have the following, how can we delete all the tags?

```
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk <a href="https://t.co/Cs0mdeYEBo" rel="nofollow noopener" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU" ><span class="tco-ellipsis"></span><span class="invisible">http://</span><span class="js-display-url">cbsn.ws/2oTosqU</span><span class="invisible"></span><span class="tco-ellipsis"><span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span></a><a href="https://t.co/rs5813GdLG" class="twitter-timeline-link u-hidden" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/rs5813GdLG</a>
```

The result after using the command should look like this:

```
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk
```

After using the following:

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

or

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'
```

I get:

```
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU&nbsp;pic.twitter.com/rs5813GdLG
```

Which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: So, by "delete all the tags", you also want to delete anything that's *within* opening and closing tags, not just the tags themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
sed -e 's/<.*>//g' <<< $var_containing_string_to_sed
```

the `<<<` is a here string, it is used to pass a string as argument instead of a file. `s/<.*>//g` indicates to `s/`(replace) string that contain character `<` followed by any character then ending by `>`.
Sed syntax is as follow : `operator/pattern to match/replacement/scope`, we have nothing between slashes which indicate to replace a pattern by ... nothing (thus delete).